# Import filt when use a pytest

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I try to import file with page elements in file with test but I always have a problem when run the test.

In folders I have file `__init__.py`

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

Try renaming the file to `__init__.py`

You might also try putting `Project`, the custom module you are importing from, in your Lib folder.

This might not work though, as you need to provide us with more information.

Comment: Thanks for ansew.
I have two folders: page (where I describe all elements in pages) and folder tests
Stucture of my progejct is:
`RT_python:
Drivers
Project:

 POMRT:

  Pages: (home_page.py)

  Tests: (test_home.py)

venv`

Comment: Yes then if the POMRT folder is not in Lib, you won't be able to import

Comment: I moved my folder with Pages.py to Lib. Now path looks 

`D:\Auto-tests\RT_python\venv\Lib\Pages`

in test i wrote 

`from venv.Lib.Pages.Login_Page import LoginPage`

but I have the same issue

Comment: I think you misunderstand. I mean the '(drive name)/programs/local/python/python(version)/Lib/POMRT'